# When Ever i build all_build in avro-cpp generated by cmake for visual studio 2010 windows xp

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, cmake, avro

**whene ever i try to build project generated by cmake it generate errors like 
"**error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515
and error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'bigrecord.hh': No such file or directory***"*

My cmake is 2.8.12.2
my Boost c++ library is 1_55_0
i am using visual studio 2010 in windows xp.

please help me for to solve this problam .. i need this for avro serialize...
if any one have other option then also reply me...

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[CMakeLists.txt](https://www.assembla.com/code/avro-cpp-windows/subversion/nodes/4/trunk/avrocpp-1.5.4-win/CMakeLists.txt) states that `bigrecord.hh` is generated by custom target `bigrecord_hh`, used only for testing. If you really want to also build testing suite, download all input files you need (e.g. `jsonschemas/bigrecord` needed in target `bigrecord.hh`)

To specify to cmake that a file is generated and hence not present during configuration, [GENERATED](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#prop_sf%3aGENERATED) property must be set to TRUE. Try add this to your CMakeLists.txt (and similarly for other generated files)

```
SET_SOURCE_FILE_PROPERTIES(${BUILD_DIRECTORY}/bigrecord.hh PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
```

Comment: be careful, this is a little bit misleading, because it implies "bigrecord.hh" must be part of the argument to include_directories, which is not the case.

Comment: I know that no any bigrecord.hh in my computer . that's why i know how to build that. because avro-cpp.sln automaticaly generated by cmake. if you have any idea than please try to solve this...